# Apace server default project location

Tags: php, apache, server, configuration

I am trying to change the root directory for my httpd projects which is by default : /var/www/html .
I have secondary drive which is mounted at /mnt/disk1 and i want it be my root directory for my httpd.
I am using fedora and i don't want to store my porjects on default directory cause i dont have much space on the boot partition.

I have tried change the DocumentRoot "/var/www/html" to DocumentRoot "/mnt/disk1/web" where web is the dir where i want to store all the projects. But its not working and it just shows me the fedora test page not matter how many solution i try.So please help me out on this one

Comment: You'll probably get a better response in Serverfault.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions. That said, when you post in Serverfault, be sure to clarify what you mean by 'its not working'.  Be sure to state what you're expecting to see.

Comment: Does the service's user have permissions in /mnt/disk1/web?